# TextView and EditText overflow

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've got a need to display and TextView (label), EditText(Input) and TextView(suffix) in a line.

The issue I have is - if the label TextView is too long it The EditText and Suffix TextView and not drawn.

Here's my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Label"
    android:id="@+id/label_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/dark_grey"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="text.." />

<TextView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="Suffix.."
    android:background="@color/lite_grey"
    android:id="@+id/suffix_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

So what I want is - even if the label is over 2-3 lines, for an EditText to appear followed by another TextView.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I've added some 'diagrams' so you can understand what I want to do a bit better.

The label to the EditText can be arbitrary length(2/3 lines), so whenever the label finishes I want an EditText to start (which is followed by another TextView showing a suffix..)

..[image: What I want]
![This shows a 2 line label and TextView..]
[image: 2 line label and EditText]

**Edit 2:** Thanks for the responses guys!! I think @questioner has really understood what I want to do i.e. I want your 3 views to move to other lines so that they behave like they were one view - and as he has suggested i'll have to find a library for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Label"
    android:id="@+id/label_text_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColorHint="@color/dark_grey"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="text.."/>

<TextView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Suffix.."
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/lite_grey"
    android:id="@+id/suffix_text_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want your 3 views to move to other lines so that they behave like they were one view - you should use external library for that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and then use `android:layout_below="@+id/..."` or `android:layout_above="@+id/..."` also `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/..."` or `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/..."`

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for each view so that they all occupy the same amount of horizontal space.

Comment: Doesn't give me what I want - I'll end up with 3 columns if the the label is very long..! I want LabelTextView, followed by EditText, Followed by SuffixTextView one after the other

Comment: horizontally or vertically?  Can you upload an image so we know exactly how you wish to size the views?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1">
```

Try this or please expand a little more.